# Where do I get tracefmt.exe? And how do I read my MSDTC traces?

Tags: windows, msdtc

I followed [the KB article from MS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899115) in order to turn on MSDTC trace. Unfortunately it was hard to follow, since it doesn't assume a very reasonable and obvious expectation of the reader, specifically "how do I read this binary log file?" I read [this page from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678917%28VS.85%29.aspx) as well, where I find that I can't read the log file because I'm missing some executable called `tracefmt.exe`, and I'm apparently the only one anywhere with this problem.

Hence my question: **Why don't I have tracefmt.exe and where do I get it?** or, to get to the point: **How do I read my MSDTC trace logs?**

Comment: Approach suggested by Thomas Bratt helped me to solve this issue (Copying the exe from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64 to the Trace folder).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tracefmt (and traceview which is easier to use) are available in the Windows Driver Kit (WDK).  It is available here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11800.  It is in the WDK since this tracing technology is more commonly used in device drivers.

Comment: Thank you! I wish the guys or girls who documented MSDTC would have included this important detail instead of referring to it consistently as "The SDK"

Comment: If you don't want to install the whole SDK, mount the ISO file, go to the WDK folder and locate the file tracingtool_x64fre_cab001.cab (x86 or ia64 depending on your architecture) and extract the file _tracefmt.exe_00002 to a folder of your choice. Rename the file to tracefmt.exe and you're done.

Answer (score 33):

With Visual Studio 2010 installed, I found the tool in the following location:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64\TraceFmt.exe`

I then copied the .EXE to the following location:

`C:\Windows\System32\Msdtc\Trace`

And ran it as follows:

`TraceFmt.exe dtctrace.log.2012-06-13-10-38-57-0601-00`

Although most of the time I use msdtcvtr.bat, as follows:

`C:\Windows\System32\Msdtc\Trace\msdtcvtr.bat -tracelog dtctrace.log.2012-06-13-10-38-57-0601-00`

Comment: Saves downloading anything, especially the massive driver kit.

Comment: I have just copied TraceFmt.exe from another server to same folder and you can use directly or with batch file. Works like a champ!!!

Answer (score 19):

To save on downloading all of the WDK (600MB+), just for 200KB of files, I opted for a 4.7MB download by doing the following:

1. Download "Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools" from here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en
2. If running from XP, just extract and go
3. If running from 2003 (like I am), you'll get an error saying this can only be installed on XP. So to get around this, use a tool to extract the exe instead.
4. Inside the exe will be a `support.cab`, extract the contents of this somewhere
5. Look for these two files, `tracefmt.exe` and `traceprt.dll`. Copy these to your `%windir%\system32\msdtc\trace` directory

Comment: It keeps telling me that traceprt.dll is missing but that dll is in the path. I also tried to register it whith regsvr32 but that didn't work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Windows 7 x64 (even after adding traceprt.dll to C:\Windows\SysWow64, then it stops complaining about the dll). Using amd64 version of tracefmt.exe from Windows DDK works fine, though.

Comment: Confirmed: it does not work for Windows 7 x64, however tracefmt.exe taken from amd64 folder magically works even with Intel processor

Answer (score 12):

### DTC Tracing

The Distributed Services Support Team blog goes over [how to trace the DTC](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112215211/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2009/02/07/the-hidden-tool-msdtc-transaction-tracing.aspx) in more detail.

### Windows Driver Kit

The links in the accepted answer seem to be broken. I've found the [Windows Driver Kit homepage](https://web.archive.org/web/20110222010513/http://www.microsoft.com:80/whdc/DevTools/WDK/default.mspx) and [current download link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800).

Once you have the ISO downloaded and you're at the installation screen, Microsoft Windows Driver Kit, select only Tools from Full Development Environment. The tracefmt.exe is in `<install-path>\<version>\Tools\tracing\i386`. *Make sure you copy the version of tracefmt.exe from the 64-bit or 32-bit directory!*

The blogger above moved those files to the DTC folder `%systemroot%\MsDtc\Trace`, probably so they were in the `msdtcvtr.bat` path.

Comment: If the server that generated the trace is a 64 bit machine, you will need to use the x64 version of exe.

Answer (score 5):

After searching for tracefmt.exe and traceprt.dll from the above posts (and elsewhere) I found that you need the 64 bit version of the tools for the program to run on Windows Server 2008.

I found [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2009/03/02/net-framework-and-windows-tools-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx).

and found that if you have visual studio installed you should be able to find both the 64-bit and 32-bit versions for the exe and dll on your local machine:

- ProgramFiles\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\ (32 bit)
- ProgramFiles\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64\ (64 bit)

Comment: True for **VS 2008**, which I was lucky to find. Unfortunately on a system with VS 2010 and VS 2012, I could not find it, neither under `Program Files` (where there is no `Microsoft SDKs` sub folder any more) nor under `Program Files (x86)`, where they seemed to have moved it.

Answer (score 2):

Tracefmt.exe comes with the Windows Driver Kit.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2105564e-1a9a-4bf4-8d74-ec5b52da3d00&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

Very often you should use existed *.mof file for enconding trace files.
In C:\Windows\System32\Msdtc\Trace\ u can see msdtctr.mof.
This file has description of the trace files and u need to use it file like this:

```
tracefmt log_filename -tmf msdtctr.mof
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Darren's and Thomas Bratt's answers quite helpful, but in order to successfully parse DTC files using `tracefmt`, I had to provide the `tmf` parameter:

```
tracefmt -tmf msdtctr.mof dtctrace.log
```

Otherwise every event turned out something like

```
Unknown( 21): GUID=75f91e0e-d50c-47c9-b06f-3f2013e9da73 (No Format Information found).
```